# NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle can get picture to display

Tags: java, android, notifications

Wondering if someone can help, i am having some trouble with `NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle` - i dont know if i am missing something, but my notification works except for the picture.. i have included a lot of the source most of it happens at the end..

```
public class OneShotAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver{
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int z = 4;          //increase this number here to the total number of affirmations
        Random rand = new Random();
        int y = rand.nextInt(z);

        String[] s = null;
        s = new String[z];  //dim
        s[0] = "i am the best and you are the most amaxzing thing on ";
        s[1] = "I love and approve of myself.";
        s[2] = "you are the re2t";
        s[3] = "you are the res3t";

        String zztitle = "";
        String zzrestofline = "";
        String string = s[y];
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    if (string.length() > 25){
        for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            // Set title to first 25 chars and rest of line to rest
           // if((i > 0) && (i % 100) == 0) {
            if(i == 25) {
                zztitle =  buffer.toString();
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                }
            // Just adds the next character to the StringBuffer.
            buffer.append(string.charAt(i));
        }
        zzrestofline =  buffer.toString();
    }
        else {
        zztitle = s[y];
    }
        setNotification(context,zzrestofline,zztitle);
        WakeLocker.acquire(context);
        Toast.makeText(context,s[y], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
private void setNotification(Context context, String zzmsg, String zztitle) {
    // http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/#Custom_View

    Bitmap remote_picture = null;
    remote_picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.retreatgoddess);

 // Create the style object with BigPictureStyle subclass.
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    notiStyle.setBigContentTitle("Big Picture Expanded");
    notiStyle.setSummaryText("Nice big picture.");

 // Add the big picture to the style.
    notiStyle.bigPicture(remote_picture);

 // Creates an explicit intent for an ResultActivity to receive.
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app

 // This ensures that the back button follows the recommended
 // convention for the back key.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

 // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself).
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

 // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack.
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(zztitle)
            .setContentText(zzmsg)
            .setTicker(zztitle)
            .setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
            .setStyle(notiStyle);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int mId = 12345; // arbitrary number
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build()); // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
```

Comment: Your code looks OK, so it seems the problem is with loading the bitmap. Try loading this image into a regular ImageView using the same code: BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.retreatgoddess); Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You should know that BigPictureStyle is only available for Android JellyBean (4.1.2) and up. NotificationCompat class takes cares of managing the compatibility with the various Android versions.
On what device version are you testing this code?